# Windows 10 no network connection after boot or sleep

Tags: windows-10, networking

For the past few months, I noticed that my computer had no network connection after waking up from sleep mode. More recently (perhaps 2 or 3 weeks) it also has no network connection after starting up.

Manually changing the adapter settings doesn't solve anything, but running the network troubleshooter does resolve the issue. The troubleshooter always identifies the problem as `The default gateway is not available` and resets the network interface to solve it.

[image: Troubleshooter screenshot]

This issue occurs both when I configure the adapter to use DHCP to find the gateway and get an IP address, as well as when I manually configure the addresses.

I don't remember doing anything specifically that might have caused this issue.

**Computer details**
Edition Windows 10 Pro
Version 20H2
Installed on    ‎2020-‎06-‎07
OS build    19042.541
Experience  Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.31.0

Comment: I occasionally have to connect my wireless connection manually on one laptop after suspend or boot but otherwise, once connected, it works very well.  Try updating 20H2 as it is now build 20226.100.  Try updating / reinstalling your network driver.

Comment: I experienced something similar with the drivers included in Windows for the 2.5G Realtek Ethernet chip (RTL8125B-CG) on my Mainboard. Using the provided version on the Realtek page solved my issue.

Comment: @John Thanks, installing the most recent windows updates solved the issue for me. Please submit as answer so that I may accept it.

Comment: I posted an appropriate answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your operating system is OS build 19042.541 which is a Windows Insider build.

Try updating to Build 20226.100 which is the most recent version.

You may also wish to update your Network Card driver.

Answer (score -3):

Check out this [article](https://www.softwaretesttips.com/default-gateway-not-available/) and try to implement the solutions mentioned in it to avoid this in the future

Comment: Try not to "just" link  to something links disappear

Comment: Welcome to SU! Please do not just refer to articles that may not exist in the future as an answer.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.